# How to use postgresql and spring boot app in same droplet on Digital Ocean

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, digital-ocean

I have installed a postgres docker container and spring boot app as another docker container.
But Spring boot app can't connect to database.

Here is my database connecting code:

```
# name is used in quartz scheduling initial table creation in db
spring.datasource.name = postgresql
# postgresql, mysql, all, h2 etc, default is all
# spring.datasource.platform = postgresql
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://<public_ip_address>:5432/production_db
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = 1234
```

Please note that Digital Ocean has also private IP address. I also tried with that. Even with localhost and 127.0.0.1

I run postgres as follows:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 5432:5432 --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.0
psql -U postgres -h localhost -c "CREATE DATABASE production_db"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Following is the docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:11.0"
    container_name: "postgresql"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234

  api:
    build: .
    container_name: "api"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
```

When I try docker-compose up --build, it also show connection error.
Datasource line:
`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/production_db`

Answer (score 0):

Please use docker compose to deploy both the application and the database, then use docker compose service name instead of public_ip_address.

Similarly i have used mysql for this sample application : https://github.com/jinternals/micrometer

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/micrometer
    username: user
    password: password
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try and will let you know

Comment: Added docker compose file content. Not working. Is the file and datasource line correct?

Comment: Yes, the sample is working. You need to use your service name(host name) in datasource url.

Comment: I mean in my case, spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/production_db is not working. See I used service name. any idea?

Comment: @Md.NajmulHasan share git url of your sample application.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPOSE 5432 in your docker command to run the Postgres container. It will not expose the port by default.

Comment: You mean in docker file right? I also tried that, not working. Thanks for collaboration